# Low performance commiting a transaction using Hibernate JPA implementation with DB2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, spring-transactions, db2-luw

I'm developing a Spring Boot application using Hibernate 5.0.11.Final JPA implementation connecting to a DB2 RDBMS.

The issue is that it takes too long to commit a transaction when the request changes (see figure 1). It takes almost 500ms only for the commit step of the whole transaction.

If I change the RDBMS to MySQL, the performance improves.

I've already tried to run REORG for the table and it doesn't help. I've tried to change the DataSource to a Hikari CP DataSource and I still get the same results.

I haven't tried changing the Hibernate code to JDBC, for it works fine with MySQL.

***DB2 v9.7.0.9 - Fix pack 9 - Platform AIX 61***

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It's 4 times faster if we implement it without Hibernate. I've just tested it (figure 2).

[XRebel output - Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV5jB.png)

[XRebel output - Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtqFB.png)

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Comment: Time to talk to your DBA.

Comment: @mustaccio I have an update on this. If I manage the transaction myself, it is 4 times faster. So, my DBA would ask me to change my code, for the DB is working fine.

Comment: @Charles DB2 v9.7.0.9 Fix pack 9 Platform AIX 61